# How to show execution time in ssms in milliseconds?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to show SQL query execution time in SSMS in milliseconds, is there any option below in ssms which show time in seconds. Is there a way ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[image]

On Right side in ssms ,the ELAPSED TIME tab shows exactly what you want

Comment: how to get this tab If it is closed ?

Comment: @PSatishPatro, the answer is View > Properties.    Good question because I don't think this properties panel is open by default.